# view infinite scroll: how to exec a js function after loading items ?

Tags: views

I have the module "views infinite scrolling" installed on my site and it works. Now I want to exec a function when all loaded (Via ajax) items are loaded and showed to the user. How can I do this ? Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably need to replace the module's JS behavior with one of your own - currently it doesn't raise any events. Or you could try [`ajaxComplete()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Drupal JS Behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors). Views Infinite Scroll should fire off Drupal behaviors on an AJAX request. You would need to add custom JS to your pages that use infinite scrolling.

[Here's an example](http://www.amazeelabs.com/en/blog/drupal-behaviors-quick-how) where someone uses this to add a class to views rows loaded from Views Infinite Scroll.

```
Drupal.behaviors.myBehaviorName = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // run your code here
  }
};
```

Comment: And then you can use that to detect the presence of the "load more" button. Views Infinite Scroll will remove it when all items are loaded. Posting code in a separate answer...

Answer (score 1):

As @romain-ni says, the latest dev version supports raising a trigger when new items are loaded, however there are patches for previous version if for some reason you can't update to the latest version of the views_infinite_scroll package

**v8.x-1.6**
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll/issues/3227982

Once this is in place you can listen for that event in your own Javascript:

```
$(document).on('views_infinite_scroll.new_content', function (evt) {
  // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will show a visually-hidden button after all items have loaded.

```
Drupal.behaviors.infiniteScrollShowButton= {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // If all items have loaded, display the "show all" button
    if ($('.view-taxonomy-term .js-pager__items a').length === 0) {
      $('.view-taxonomy-term .view-footer a.button').removeClass('visually-hidden');
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Un patch existe pour l'ajout d'un évènement jQuery au chargement de contenu : https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll/issues/3164903

On y ajoute deux triggers :

- "*views_infinite_scroll.new_content*" : au chargement des éléments
- "*views_infinite_scroll.new_content.appended*" : une fois que les éléments sont présents dans le DOM

Le premier trigger devrait intégrer la prochaine version stable ***8.x-1.8***, puisqu'il est déjà disponible dans la version ***8.x-1.x-dev***

Ensuite pour détecter l'évènement :

`$(document).on('views_infinite_scroll.new_content', (e) => {...})`